# findnext() method in xml document

Tags: c#, xml, find

one more question about xml document. so, i want to find messages by message body (text) and i wrote find() method:

```
public void find(string searchText)
{
    XmlNodeList smss = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//sms");
    searchText = txtFind.Text;

    foreach (XmlNode sms in smss)
    {
        if (sms.Attributes["body"].InnerText.Contains(searchText))
        {
            txtName.Text = sms.Attributes["body"].InnerText +
                           sms.Attributes["time"].Value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

this method finds first message which contains search string and writes it on txtName textbox. now, i want to find next message which contains the same string and add it to txtname textbox, in other words i want to write findNext() method. i can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Any reason you want to use `XmlNode` etc here, rather than LINQ to XML?

Comment: no reason. how to do it with linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a for loop and store the state of the counter, then jump counter elements from the XMLNodeList and start searching again from there, for example:

```
//Assumes i is declared somewhere else 
for (i ; i < smss.Count; i++)
{
    if (smss[i].Attributes["body"].InnerText.Contains(searchText))
    {
        txtName.Text = smss[i].Attributes["body"].InnerText +
                       smss[i].Attributes["time"].Value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, without break; it can find all messages with searching word but it don't finds the next message if i use break; operator. why is that?

Comment: @samuraisxmali because it is c#. You do understand, that without break you will have only last sms in your textbox?

Comment: yes, i have it if i don't use index 'i', but with it i have all messages. your method helped a lot. but if you could do this: "i want 'find next' button like it is in notepad and every time i click on it, it finds next word, but in this program i want to find next message with the same word." that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure if its something like this you are looking for but hopefully the following example might be able to help you

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If OptionButton1 Then
Dim MyValue, MyFindNext
    [A1].Select
    MyValue = TextBox1.Value

    On Error GoTo err_Trap
    Cells.Find(What:=MyValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate

    MyFindNext = vbYes
    Do Until MyFindNext <> vbYes
    MyFindNext = MsgBox("Would you like to find the next instance of " & MyValue & "?", _
        vbYesNo, "Find Next")
        If MyFindNext = vbNo Then
        Unload UserForm1
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
End If

If OptionButton2 Then
    [A1].Select
    MyValue = TextBox1

    On Error GoTo err_Trap
    Cells.Find(What:=MyValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate

    MyFindNext = vbYes
    Do Until MyFindNext <> vbYes
    MyFindNext = MsgBox("Would you like to find the next instance of " & MyValue & "?", _
        vbYesNo, "Find Next")
        If MyFindNext = vbNo Then
        Unload UserForm1
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

err_Trap:
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        MsgBox "Could not find " & MyValue & " anywhere on this sheet.", , "Search failed"
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Refer to this link for more information

http://www.knowexcel.com/view/931222-findnext-method-help-.html